# How to read Properties file using Jquery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried using `jQuery.i18n.properties({}); plugin` from this reference [site](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/) but it's not working.

Is there any another way to read properties file in JavaScript or jQuery so that the contents can be loaded on an HTML page?

Comment: Is the access attempt cross-domain? Is it for a `http:`/`https:` resource or for a `file://` resource? Do you see any errors in your JavaScript console? Please post a sample of your code.

Comment: yes its http:// as i am trying to read the property file using localhost i.e IIS server and on console its showing 404 [file not found] but i have checked the throughtly the path is perfect

Comment: Just so we're clear: have you looked in your network console and verified that the Ajax request produced by the plugin is a request for a resource on the *exact correct path*? That is, if you copy the URL directly out of your browser's network console (for example, in chrome, find your network console with `F12` and go to the "Network" tab) and paste it into your address bar, it works?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/test/bundle/Messages.properties?_=1377629072062  It show this ERROR but the path to the file is correct one And when i copy and paste the url under the network tab i get "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found"

Answer (score 1):

I think including MIME type to IIS will work

Add

'**.properties**' MIME extension and add type '**text/plain**'.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically (see previous answer) you can do that in two ways:

1) web.config (recommended) - add the following 2 elements :

```
<configuration>
...
   <system.webServer>
   ...
      <staticContent>
      ...
         <remove fileExtension="properties" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension="properties" mimeType="text/plain" />
```

2) IIS - you need to do that every time you deploy to a new IIS

- open IIS manager
- select either the machine node or the web site node (usually Default  Web Site)
- In the Features View - locate the "Mime Types" icon under the IIS section.
- add the mime type:

  - File name extension: ".properties" (make sure you have the dot at the beginning)
  - Mime type: "text/plain"